# how to prevent javascript div popup from jumping back to the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, css, html, popup

I have the following neat code that opens a small popup box when the link is clicked ...the problem is that I use it on a very long page with lots of content, and whenever someone opens the popup, the actual content page jumps back to the very top, which is annoying if someone just spent a while scrolling down. How can I force the page to stay there even though the popup window is opened/closed?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showPopUp(el) {
                var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
                var dlg = document.getElementById(el)
                cvr.style.display = "block"
                dlg.style.display = "block"
                if (document.body.style.overflow = "hidden") {
                    cvr.style.width = "1024"
                    cvr.style.height = "100%"
                }
            }
            function closePopUp(el) {
                var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
                var dlg = document.getElementById(el)
                cvr.style.display = "none"
                dlg.style.display = "none"
                document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll"
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #cover {
                display:none;
                position:absolute;
                left:0px;
                top:0px;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                background:gray;
                filter:alpha(Opacity=50);
                opacity:0.5;
                -moz-opacity:0.5;
                -khtml-opacity:0.5
            }
            #dialog {
                display:none;
                position:absolute;
                top:50%;
                left:50%;
                width:400px;  /* adjust as per your needs */
                height:400px;   /* adjust as per your needs */
                margin-left:-200px;   /* negative half of width above */
                margin-top:-200px;   /* negative half of height above */
                z-index:100;
                background:white;
                padding:2px;
                font:10pt tahoma;
                border:1px solid gray
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cover"></div>
        <div id="dialog">
            My Dialog Content
            <br><input type="text">
            <br><input type="button" value="Submit">
            <br><a href="#" onclick="closePopUp('dialog');">[Close]</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#" onclick="showPopUp('dialog');">Show</a>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a library the wheel was invented couple of years ago...

Comment: Sorry, I searched high and low before asking but I'm a javascript dummy and can't find the answer myself. I searched and didn't find anything that made sense...

Comment: Is it similar to this issue? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155952/how-do-i-prevent-scrolling-to-the-top-of-a-page-when-popping-up-a-jquery-ui-dial)

Comment: Take a look at the [jQuery ui-dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Comment: I tried adding a return false; to the end of the function but that didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

change this code:

```
from <a href="#" onclick="closePopUp('dialog');">[Close]</a>
```

to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closePopUp('dialog');">[Close]</a>
```

and also:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showPopUp('dialog');">Show</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showPopUp('dialog');">Show</a>
```

Try that.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. It shows the popup box but off the screen at the very top.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the link to open the popup, you are actually navigating to "#" which causes the scrollbar to go back to the top of the page. You really shouldn't use the onclick attribute anymore, it's better to attach an event listener to an element with Javascript.

As mentioned by user Sammy above, using `href="javascript:void(0)"` should prevent this behavior. Personally I like to just leave the `href` attribute off of the `<a>` tag if I'm not actually using it as a standard link. The only downside is that you need to re-style the link to look like a normal link as it will be styled differently if it's missing the `href` attribute.

I've made a [JSFiddle with a solution](https://jsfiddle.net/Hendeca/d6tkdv2q/1/). As you can see, I removed the `href` attribute and re-styled the links, using Javascript to add event handlers for the links. You can scroll down a bit and click the link; the popup will open and the scrollbar will remain in the same position.

The code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="cover"></div>
  <div id="dialog">
    My Dialog Content
    <br><input type="text">
    <br><input type="button" value="Submit">
    <br><a class="close-button" data-popup="dialog">[Close]</a>
  </div>
  <a class="show-button" data-popup="dialog">Show</a>   
</div>
```

JS

```
var showButton = document.getElementsByClassName('show-button');
var closeButton = document.getElementsByClassName('close-button');

showButton[0].addEventListener('click', showPopUp);
closeButton[0].addEventListener('click', closePopUp);

function showPopUp(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    var dialogId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-popup');
    var scrollPos = window.scrollY;
    var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
    var dlg = document.getElementById(dialogId)
    cvr.style.display = "block"
    dlg.style.display = "block"
    window.scroll(0, scrollPos);
}
function closePopUp(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    var dialogId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-popup');
    var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
    var dlg = document.getElementById(dialogId)
    cvr.style.display = "none"
    dlg.style.display = "none"
}
```

CSS

```
.container {
  height: 5000px;
}

.show-button,
.close-button { 
  position: fixed; 
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.show-button:hover,
.close-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#cover {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:gray;
  filter:alpha(Opacity=50);
  opacity:0.5;
  -moz-opacity:0.5;
  -khtml-opacity:0.5
}
#dialog {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  width:400px;  /* adjust as per your needs */
  height:400px;   /* adjust as per your needs */
  margin-left:-200px;   /* negative half of width above */
  margin-top:-200px;   /* negative half of height above */
  z-index:100;
  background:white;
  padding:2px;
  font:10pt tahoma;
  border:1px solid gray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
<a href="#" onclick="closePopUp('dialog');">[Close]</a>
```

to

```
<a onclick="closePopUp('dialog');">[Close]</a>
```

and this

```
<a href="#" onclick="showPopUp('dialog');">Show</a>
```

to

```
<a onclick="showPopUp('dialog');">Show</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

try using position:fixed instead of position:absolute.
For more read: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp